# How to test raw sql entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a sql-script that I want to execute in a unit test with entity framework. When I'm using the InMemoryDb(not SQLite), I get the following error:

```
"Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider.
```

I have tried to use SQLite, but I get this error when trying to execute the SQL:

```
SQLite Error 1: 'near \"DECLARE\": syntax error'.
```

This because SQLite is using another SQL dialect.

Here is the first part of my sql script:

```
DECLARE @uniqueAccountsAndNames AS TABLE(
    [GlobalId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER INDEX ix UNIQUE,
    [RowNumber] INT, 
    [Account] NVARCHAR(100) INDEX IX2 NONCLUSTERED,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(500),
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(500),
    [Source] NVARCHAR(50)
);
```

Here is my code in the unit test:

```
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("datasource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();


        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SecurityContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection)
            .Options;


        using (var context = new SecurityContext(options))
        {

            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            SeedData(context);
            var sqll = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"test.sql");
            var test = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqll);
        }
```

Do you have any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe a SQL Server LocalDB?

Comment: @mu88 that requires that I download and installs it..

Comment: And that's a problem? If so, you might add this requirement to your post  Another option would be to convert the unit into an integration test and use a preconfigured Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unit test SQL, then you should be testing with SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/walkthrough-creating-and-running-a-sql-server-unit-test?view=sql-server-ver15